# How to create a new user without home directory and with specific UID

Tags: command-line, users, gnome-terminal, adduser

How can I add a new user "Kids" with UID = 500 and without home directory with `adduser` command in terminal? I'm trying this: `sudo adduser --no-create-home --uid ID 500 Kids` and after correctly entering password it says that value "ID" is invalid for option uid. Then I have tried the same thing only without "ID" and got: Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured via the NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.

Answer (score 4):

First - UIDs less than 1000 are usually system reserved, pick a higher UID.

Second - Why are you wanting it to not have a home directory.  Keep in mind the --no-create-home doesn't mean the user doesn't have a home directory assigned, it just isn't created.  An error will be logged every time that user logs in.

Third - Please remember to post errors your get, else we can only assume as to what the problem is.  I'm assuming it has to do with the name format, in which case, you can bypass this using --force-badname, as the error message would say, or use all lower case characters.

*edit typo

Answer (score 3):

`adduser` command will let you include all the default home directories automatically. So you can not with adduser directly.

you can use `useradd` instead.

```
sudo useradd <username>
```

will create the user with the given user name.

While coming to UID , the Range 499 reserved for system users i.e in Linux each service creates its own user and below 499 UID will allocated for those users.
hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`useradd -M username` --- creates user without home directory

we can check it as `tail -5 /etc/passwd` which doesnot show the users home directory as it shows **nologin**

```
useradd -u userspecificid username
```

user specific id will be displayed after 999

Comment: where is the answer for specific UID ?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use "adduser".

Try again with:

```
adduser -u 500 kids --no-create-home
```